# Post Featured Image block not being rendered when post content is fetched directly

Tags: wordpress, rest, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm maintaining a custom REST endpoint for a WordPress site to which they've just added a new custom post type. The REST response has a `content` object which simply contains all of the post's content:

```
$magData->content = apply_filters('the_content', get_post_field('post_content', $magID));
```

However, while regular image blocks and even custom blocks (created with ACF) are output in this `content` object with no issue, it looks like the core **Post Featured Image Block** isn't rendering at all:

[image: The custom JSON REST response showing the content object with a bunch of '\n\n\n' character where the image block should be.]

As you can see, it simply renders a bunch of line breaks (`\n\n\n\n`) instead of the expected `<figure>` element. I would expect any Gutenberg Block elements to be rendered once the `the_content` filter is applied to it, but it doesn't look like that's working for this specific block.

For reference, here's what the block looks like in Gutenberg - it just uses the post's own Featured Image for its image content:

[image: WordPress Gutenberg editor showing the Post Featured Image Block highlighted as a picture icon with 2 strokes beneath it.]

Looking at the post's `post_content` in the database, the Post Featured Image block is simply a self-closing comment block: `<!-- wp:post-featured-image /-->` - and in the actual page source, it gets rendered as:

```
<figure class="wp-block-post-featured-image"><img loading="lazy" width="1280" height="853" src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/field.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" srcset="{some_image_sizes}" /></figure>
```

So I'm left scratching my head as to why a Post Featured Image Block would render just fine in the actual WP front end, but not when called using `apply_filters('the_content', $content)`.

Comment: Which version of WordPress are you testing on? Is there any value in the REST response for `featured_media` returned?

Comment: @S.Walsh Currently running the latest WP 6.0. And this isn't a regular `wp-json` REST response - it's a custom one the client has for feeding to their app. But there's a call for `get_the_post_thumbnail_url($postID)` in there that returns the featured image as expected. It's this block in the post context that does nothing with the above filter.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't replicate the issue. I suspect there could be a conflicting filter applied on `the_content` elsewhere in the custom endpoint code. Another potential cause is the site URL not pointing to the actual location of the image leading the [post featured image](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-library/src/post-featured-image/index.php#L26) block to return nothing - let us know what you find?

Comment: @S.Walsh I suspect the issue is because the block code is effectively contextless (i.e. it doesn't contain any actual reference to the post or iD); and the custom REST code isn't using a global `$post` object, that it has no reference for the image, so it's outputting nothing. Client has said they're not that bothered now, so ‍♀️